Create a type from a json array of objects
I have a json file with an array of this structure:
    [
      {
        "code": "TEST",
        "name": "Testing",
      },
...rest
    ]

I would like to make a new type declaration of all the codes of this array.
I have tried
const statusTypeCodes = statusTypes.map(t => t.code) as const
type StatusCode = typeof statusTypeCodes[number];

but it won't allow that first line.
Whats the best way to do this?

You need to use as const when you define the object literal:
const statusTypes = [
    {
      "code": "TEST",
      "name": "Testing",
    },
    {
      "code": "TEST2",
      "name": "Testing2",
    },
] as const;

type StatusCode = typeof statusTypes[number]["code"]; // "TEST" | "TEST2";


If the JSON file is going to be a static file in your repo, I recommend moving it to a module and using as const. If your JSON is imported from a JSON file and this is not an option you will be blocked for now by https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063.
